# How to insert a WebView into a cocoa app?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, interface, webkit, builder

I'm rather new with the whole OSX programming, I wanted to stick a WebView into an empty app. Apparently it isn't as simple as sticking a WebView on a window in interface builder and creating an outlet.

```
IBOutlet WebView *webView;
```

It gives me a

```
expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'WebView'
```

and when I don't use an outlet, it terminates due to uncaught exception. I'm not too sure what these error messages mean.

Seems it isn't that simple!

Comment: iphone or desktop? 
You might also need to right click on the project and go to  Add -> Existing Frameworks and add webkit.framework to your project.

Comment: Desktop, Thanks Chris - I needed to add the framework! Guess I assumed it was already there! Now I'm faced with the entire window being white with none of my controls showing up...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need to add the WebKit framework to your target and forward declare `WebView` or import the header file:

```
// header file:
@class WebView; // forward declaration sufficient in header
@interface WhatEver ... {
    WebView* webview;
// ...
@property (assign) IBOutlet WebView *webview;
@end

// implementation file:
#import <WebKit/WebView.h> // if you want to do something with the WebView
@implementation WhatEver
@synthesize webview;
// ...
@end
```

Comment: So far so good. No errors and the app shows, it's just white though. I have noticed I can right click reload..

I've got

[[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]]];

attached to a button

Comment: @spamoom: That works just fine for me - are you sure that code is executed?

Comment: I re-created the project and it worked fine.. must have been something funny in that one...

Answer (score 5):

Did you try to link the WebKit framework, then importing it?

```
#import "WebKit/WebKit.h"
```